# Execute asyncronus function from shared library in a new thread (Rust)

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, plugins, rust, rust-tokio

I was following Michael-F-Bryan's [Dynamic Loading & Plugins](https://michael-f-bryan.github.io/rust-ffi-guide/dynamic_loading.html) chapter from his Rust FFI guide, but I am storing the plugins in a `HashMap` (`HashMap<&'static str, Box<dyn Plugin>`) instead of a `Vec` so that I can call the functions of a `Plugin` individually.

I would like the plugins to define a asynchronous function with it's own loop that communicates with the main part of the application using channels ([`std`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/fn.channel.html) or [`tokio`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.0.1/tokio/sync/mpsc/fn.channel.html)).

Working around the fact that you can't have `async` functions in traits was easy thanks to the [async_trait](https://crates.io/crates/async-trait) crate, but the issue that I am now facing is, that I cannot spawn a new thread with the module because the new thread might outlive the `PluginManager`.

I tried to recreate this in a rust playground without the dynamic modules and I'm facing the same error [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=60a421231d48b7587051f4a0e24dd73f) (note: this does not include any kind of channel communication)

Unlike the first error, I was unable to recreate a rust playground for the second one (as it happens at runtime). Instead of spawning a new thread, I was using tokio's event loop to handle the `async` functions. This works in the [sandbox](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=69d671ce1e8ae944526eadb6e7dff81e), but not when using a shared library as plugin. At runtime it throws:

```
thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'there is no timer running, must be called from the context of Tokio runtime', /home/admin/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tokio-1.0.1/src/time/driver/handle.rs:50:18
```

If someone knows a solution around this problem, or even had the same issue, it would be great if you could share them with me as I've already tried so much but nothing worked in my favor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've already recognized the problem: a reference to an object owned by the `PluginManager` is being moved into a future that is being spawned, and thus may run on another thread than the one which owns the `PluginManager`. The compiler cannot know that the future will not outlive the `PluginManager`.

There are a number of possible solutions to this, for example:

- Store the plugin instances inside `Arc<Box<T>>`, so that they are reference counted in runtime. Then even if the plugin manager did not live as long as the futures you are spawning, it would not matter
- Make the `PluginManager` an immutable static singleton

In this case I suspect you want the `PluginManager` to be a singleton. You can do that by replacing the `new` constructor with a `get` method that lazily constructs the instance and returns a reference to it:

```rust
use once_cell::sync::Lazy;

impl PluginManager {

    pub fn get() -> &'static Self {
        static PLUGINMANAGER: Lazy<PluginManager> = Lazy::new(|| {
            let mut mgr = PluginManager {
                plugins: HashMap::new()
            };
            mgr.load_plugins();
            mgr
        });
        &PLUGINMANAGER
    }
// ...
}
```

Note that this lazy constructor fully initializes the static instance, including loading the plugins.

It uses `once_cell::sync::Lazy` from the [once_cell](https://docs.rs/once_cell/1.5.2/once_cell/) crate. This functionality is also available in [nightly std](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/lazy/struct.Lazy.html), so it will eventually become part of the standard library.

The `spawn_plugins` function needs to be altered slightly to specify that it requires a static self:

```
pub async fn spawn_plugins(&'static self) {
//...
```

and finally your main function becomes:

```
async fn main() {
    let mgr = PluginManager::get();
    mgr.spawn_plugins().await;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7ad1b4fb9d815cb0db5ddbf58671d8da)

Regarding your other problem, that's a separate issue - stack overflow works best if you post one problem at a time.

Comment: While this solves the problem of spawning a new thread, I face the same issue that I've already mentioned above, that the thread() method is not part of the tokio runtime and thus I can't use async.

But as this is now a new thread, I could make the async function a non-async one, and spawn a blocking tokio thread in the thread() function.